# how to block telnet somehow

Tags: networking, telnet, network-security

Scenario: 
Scenario:
In this part we have two System Administrators who administer a system which has
windows OS installed. First Admin is beside the system and second Admin is on
vacation. Both have username and password. In a negligence, second Admin left his
notebook containing login information and Server IP in a CafeNet. An intruder from a
black hat hackers group found it and decided to go another unknown place to access
the server using telnet. But that takes 10 minutes to get there. Imagine you informed
right from beginning minute. Now help first Admin to configure the system in a way
that while receiving any telnet connection, it warns the intruder with a message and
let him know that we have already covered this security hole. But, if it was a request
of second Admin (he calls or chat you!), then we let him to go ahead with telnet
connection!
Note: For some reasons, we can not stop Telnet, or change password today!

Answer (score 0):

Well from the command line there is no way to do that, but I guess that you could make an application that would be capable of doing so and apply that to the Telnet server. Telnet cannot specifically be commanded to warn an intruder, it can only run the commands that it was intended to do.